# Disable Touch Gestures in Android Browser via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, webkit, touch

Does anyone know how to disable touch gestures using JavaScript while running content in the browser on Android?

For example, I want to disable the pinch to zoom gesture via JavaScript.

Comment: I would pay for an iPhone browser that ignores the `user-scalable=no` meta tag. I *hate* it when sites won't let me zoom.

Comment: I am interested in this issue too. I want to disable the double-click zoom when clicking a specific image. The user has to click this image as fast as he can for 10 seconds which causes a lot of unwanted zooms on android browsers. Unfortunately listening to the touchend event and using prevenDefault() and stopPropagation() on the event does not solve the problem.

Comment: Note that most competent mobile browsers allow you to set an option to zoom regardless of the author's settings, usually under Accessibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be done with the meta tag, viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

I'm not sure if it's possible with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. (You are missing a closing quote in the content attribute).

Comment: One issue with this on iOS and Android, is that it will cause line drawing in the Canvas element to be Aliased (and generally look crappy).

Comment: This wont work on HTC devices running Android as they ignore the meta viewport tag (annoyingly)

Answer (score 1):

To add it with JavaScript:

```
var vp = document.createElement('meta');
vp.name = "viewport";
vp.content = "width=device-width; user-scalable=no;";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( vp );
```